# How do you get ESLint working with VSCode, NVM, and Vue?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, nvm

TL;DR: ESlint loads, but doesn't lint my files in VSCode. I've tried:

- ensuring the plugin is enabled
- ensuring Eslint is running in `lint output` window in VSCode
- disabling ESLint in VSCode, reloading it, enabling it, reloading it - no change
- ensuring it's enabled, and then restarting machine
- Running it on the command line - which works

Story:
I'm working in VSCode. Can't get ESLint to work (the way I want) on my project within VSCode, with one exception. There are some library files that it lints relentlessly - all the ones in `src/` or other Vue project dir's, not so much. So I thought it was the `eslintrc`. To disprove this, however, I run yarn lint - and it lints all the files in the vue directories specified by my eslint.

So definitely seems like an integrating with VSCode issue. Here are the details that are likely getting in the way:

- I use NVM for node version management. Maybe VSCode isn't using the right version?

Comment: I found [this article](https://medium.com/@doppelmutzi/eslint-prettier-vue-workflow-46a3cf54332f) quite helpful. Maybe it can help you set things up correctly.

Comment: Please, have a look [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/42#issuecomment-318859607) too. Maybe it helps.